# .NET DLL object in COM EXE unable to be instantiated

Tags: .net, vb6, interop

I have an issue that is only happening on one machine.

Here is the scenario.  I have an EXE that is currently still developed in VB6, but I successfully migrated it's DLL to .NET.  The EXE houses an object reference to a class in the DLL, and during startup initializes the object with the referenced DLL.

For some reason only on one machine it is unable to initialize the object, even though the DLL is properly registered (using ragasm.exe).  All other machines do not have a problem.

The machine with the problem is a Windows XP 32-bit computer, and the user is logged in as an admin.  I have even manually registered the DLL, with no problems, but the program still cannot create the reference to it.

Not sure what other steps I could take to debug this problem.  Logically it should be working since it is registered properly.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Let me verify I understand things correctly: You have a VB6 executable that instantiates a COM object hosted in a VB6 DLL. So far, so good. You said you've migrated the DLL to .NET, and that's where it gets fuzzy. Have you rewritten part of the program in .NET, and are using the VB6 DLL through interop? Sorry to seem dense, just making sure I've got the pieces right :) (I would mention that registering a DLL would be done via regsvr32 typically)..

Comment: Your .Net dll depends on the correct version of .Net Framework. Make sure this XP has the framework you are using for your .Net dll installed ok.

Comment: What error are you getting when it is "unable to initialize the object"?

Comment: Sorry about any confusion, it is a .NET (Framework 2.0) DLL (that used to be a VB6 DLL).  I have checked to make sure he has .NET Framework 2.0 installed (and he has up to 3.5 installed), and the error is just "Automation Error" and my custom message letting me know what object has the problem.
I can manually register the DLL using the standard .NET regasm.exe process, and it indicates that everything is fine.  I will have to try what tcarvin suggests below to see if it can give me more insight to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use process monitor to see where your app goes off track.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

You should see the VB6 app hit the registry to find the location of the DLL, and then see it access the filesystem to locate the DLL.  Post back with results if you are still stuck after that.